# Cannot Pass an onTap Field to a Stateless Widget

Tags: flutter, snackbar

In a grid view, since I have similar card items, I decided to create a custom widget containing each card item. The custom widget is a stateless widget. The problem I have is in passing an onTap property to the class. In fact, I do pass and no errors are there, but the onTap property does not propagate properly and it does not display the SnackBar I want. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const _padding = EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
const _splashColor = Colors.amber;

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Main Page'),),
      drawer: Drawer(
        elevation: 8.0,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
           DrawerHeader(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/top_picture.png'), fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, width: 100, height: 100),
                  Text('Home', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6)
                ],
              )),
          ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Settings')),
          ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app), title: Text('Quit')),
          AboutListTile(icon: Icon(Icons.info), aboutBoxChildren: [Text('Copyright (C) 2020'), Text('Design And Programming: me')],)
        ],
      )),
      body: HomeScreenBody(),
    );
  }
}



class HomeScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Padding (
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: GridView (
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              children: [
                ItemCard(title: 'Balance', icon: 'assets/images/coins-balance.png', onTap: _comingSoon),
                ItemCard(title: 'Add Funds', icon: 'assets/images/add-money.png', onTap: _comingSoon,),
                ItemCard(title: 'Restaurant', icon: 'assets/images/restaurant.png', onTap: _comingSoon),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  void _comingSoon(BuildContext context) {
    print('Showing snackbar...');
    final snack = SnackBar(content: Text('Coming soon...'));
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
  }
}



class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget{
  final String icon;

  final String title;

  final ValueChanged<BuildContext> onTap;

  const ItemCard({this.title, this.icon, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Builder(builder:(context) {
      return  Card(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: _splashColor,
          onTap: ()=> this.onTap,
          child: Column (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image(image: Image.asset(this.icon).image, ),
              Padding(
                padding: _padding,
                child: Text(this.title),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },

    );
  }
}
```

I tried changing the type of onTap field to ValueChanged, ValueChanged, ValueChanged<BuildContext), but none of them worked. Any idea why my callback is not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget{
  final String icon;

  final String title;

  final void Function(BuildContext) onTap; //your function expects a context

  const ItemCard({this.title, this.icon, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Builder(builder:(ctx) { //changed to ctx so that contexts don't clash
      return  Card(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: _splashColor,
          onTap: ()=> this.onTap(context), //pass context here
          child: Column (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image(image: Image.asset(this.icon).image, ),
              Padding(
                padding: _padding,
                child: Text(this.title),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },

    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.. there is other simple way too.

Comment: Interesting. This works! Seems like it's because I didn't pass context inside onTap of InkWell.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a `VoidCallback` for your `onTap` variable.
2. Wrap the `HomeScreen` widget tree with a `Builder` widget so a `context` to be used in the `SnackBar` can be available.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

---

This works:

```dart
class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget{
  final String icon;

  final String title;

  final VoidCallback onTap; // use a VoidCallback instead

  const ItemCard({this.title, this.icon, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Builder(builder:(context) {
      return  Card(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: _splashColor,
          onTap: onTap, // assign the onTap property
          child: Column (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image(image: Image.asset(this.icon).image, ),
              Padding(
                padding: _padding,
                child: Text(this.title),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },

    );
  }
```

```dart
class HomeScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Builder(
        builder: (context){,
              child: Padding (
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: GridView (
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                children: [
                  ItemCard(title: 'Balance', icon: 'assets/images/coins-balance.png', onTap: () => _comingSoon(context)),
                  ItemCard(title: 'Add Funds', icon: 'assets/images/add-money.png', onTap: () => _comingSoon(context),),
                  ItemCard(title: 'Restaurant', icon: 'assets/images/restaurant.png', onTap: () => _comingSoon(context)),
                ],
              ),
            );
        },
      );
  }

  void _comingSoon(context) {
    print('Showing snackbar...');
    final snack = SnackBar(content: Text('Coming soon...'));
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I wonder, though, what's the difference between `onTap: this.onTap` and `onTap:()=>this.onTap` inside InkWell. The latter does not work.  Is `VoidCallback` the same as `void Function(BuildContext)`?

Comment: Nope, `VoidCallback` isn't the same as `Function(BuildContext)`. VoidCallback doesn't require parameters. @codezombie

Answer (score 0):

Change widget's `onTap` parameter to be a `final Function(BuildContext)` and then in `onTap:` change `()=> this.onTap` to `onTap()`. That should do it.

Comment: Actually, it needs context too. Does not work without it.

Comment: Indeed. My mistake. Edited my answer.