# Flutter provider can't re-render immediately

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Here is my source code: https://github.com/liou-jia-hao/flutter_demo_app/tree/Cannot-refresh

I create a file which contains my counter model called "counter.dart", here is code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:nanoid/nanoid.dart';

class Counter {
  String id;
  int count;

  void increment() {
    count++;
  }

  void decrement() {
    count--;
  }

  Counter(this.id, this.count);
}

class CountersModel with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Counter> countersMap = {};

  void createCounter() {
    var id = nanoid();
    countersMap[id] = Counter(id, 0);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And here is my main.dart code:

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, lines_longer_than_80_chars
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'models/counter.dart';

/// This is a reimplementation of the default Flutter application using provider + [ChangeNotifier].

void main() {
  runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CountersModel()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var countersSet = context.select<CountersModel, Set<Counter>>(
        (model) => model.countersMap.values.toSet());
    var countersModel = context.read<CountersModel>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: countersSet.map((counter) => BlueButton(counter)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        key: const Key('increment_floatingActionButton'),

        /// Calls `context.read` instead of `context.watch` so that it does not rebuild
        /// when [Counter] changes.
        onPressed: countersModel.createCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlueButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlueButton(this.counter, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Counter counter;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: counter.increment,
      onLongPress: counter.decrement,
      child: Column(
        children: [Text(counter.id), Text('${counter.count}')],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I expected the number on the BlueButton can increase immediately.
But the number on the BlueButton can't increase immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your counter needs context in order for the button to change.
Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63756434/cannot-pass-an-ontap-field-to-a-stateless-widget).